# How may I get these values using a query

Tags: mysql

I have a table called **Levenstein**

With the following column names and dataset :

```
**Meal****Ingredients****Occurence**
Soup       Tomate          4
Soup       Maggi          100
Soup       Onions          23
Soup       Salt           300
Soup       Pepper         345
Lasagne    Cheese         234
Lasagne    Butter         2422
Lasagne    Beef            42
Lasagne    Salt            244
.
.
```

Occurrence is basically the amount of times which a user used that ingredient so for Soup for example, many users used Pepper than anything else. Thats just the logic to make you understand the data.

I want a query to give me the most used ingredient for each meal as well as the ingredient name. So finally i will have :

```
**Meal****Ingredients****Occurence**
    Soup       Pepper         345  
    Lasagne    Butter         2422
    .
    .
```

Comment: @Oyeme maybe i can't do it ? an effort isn't obligatory to ask a question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT Meal, Ingredients, Occurence
FROM table JOIN
(SELECT Meal as m, MAX(Occurence) as Max_Occurence FROM table GROUP BY Meal) T ON table.m = T.Meal
WHERE table.Occurence = T.Max_Occurence
```

Comment: Which ingredient is that going to give you?

Comment: @sarwar026 Thanks for your reply "Meal" appears as ambiguous

Comment: @beginningperl: got it. Meal is in both table. You already use alias to solve the ambiguity. Thanks.